# Why is $f^{-1}(y_0)$ open in this proof?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation

Notes: the theorem below is set in the context of multivariable calculus. Here $f:X\to F$ is a differentiable function, $X\subset E$, and $E,F$ are Banach spaces, and $\partial f$ without any subindex means total derivative of $f$.

Also $(3.7)$ is a previous theorem that says that if $X$ is convex and $\partial f:X\to\mathcal L(E,F)$ is bounded then $f$ is Lipschitz continuous.

> **Theorem:** if $X$ is connected and $\partial f=0$, then $f$ is constant. **Proof:** let $\Bbb B(x_0,r)\subset X$ an open ball around $x_0$. Letting $y_0:=f(x_0)$ from $(3.7)$ follows that $f(x)=y_0$ for all $x\in\Bbb B(x_0,r)$. Because $x_0$ was arbitrary then $f$ is locally constant. Therefore $f^{-1}(y_0)$ is non-empty and open in $X$. Also $f^{-1}(y_0)$ is closed in $X$ because $f$ is continuous, and because $X$ is connected then $f^{-1}(y_0)=X$.

I dont follow why $f^{-1}(y_0)$ is supposed to be open in $X$. Can someone enlighten me please? Thank you in advance.

Comment: "from (3.7) follows that $f(x)=y_0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{B}(x_0,r)$". This tells you that $f^{-1}(y_0)$ contains a ball around any of its points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is locally constant. Hence if $x\in f^{-1}(y_0)$, then $f^{-1}(y_0)$ is a neighbourhood of $x$. As $f^{-1}(y_0)$ is a neighbourhood for all its elements, it must be open.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f$ is locally constant about $x_0$ i.e there exists a $ U$ open set about $x_0$ such that $f|_U \equiv \textbf{constant}$. But since $f(x_0) = y_0$ then $f|_U = y_0 \Rightarrow f^{-1}(y_0) = U$.